# How to optimize rendering of many textures in SDL 2?

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, rendering, sdl-2

I'm using SDL 2 and I have a 2D-array of 8x8 px blocks:

```
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xdf, 0xef, 0xff, 0xff);
    for (s32 y = 0, Y = 0; y < worldSize.y; y++, Y += blockSize)
        for (s32 x = 0, X = 0; x < worldSize.x; x++, X += blockSize)
            if (block[x][y].GetMaterial())
            {
                if (block[x][y].IsSolid())
                {
                    SDL_Rect src =
                    {
                        block[x][y].GetTileVariant() * blockSize,
                        block[x][y].GetTile() * blockSize,
                        blockSize,
                        blockSize
                    };
                    SDL_Rect dst =
                    {
                        X + (s32)posX,
                        Y + (s32)posY,
                        blockSize,
                        blockSize
                    };
                    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, materials[block[x][y].GetMaterial()]->texture, &src, &dst);
                }
            }
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

So here I use a few textures in random order, e.g.: 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, etc. And if it fills all screen (1920x1080), it stars to lag. Not so much, but anyway aloud. So my question is: how to optimize it? What should I use? I need some code example. At last, should I write something on openGL by my own or what to do?

Comment: Eventually something like https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1734 will land. In the meantime you can compile from my fork here: https://bitbucket.org/gabomdq/sdl-1.3-experimental/commits/branch/RenderGeometry

Answer (score 2):

Try grouping your `SDL_RenderCopy()` calls by material/texture and hope your OpenGL driver fast-paths redundant `glBindTexture()`s.

And/or group all your tiles into one large texture atlas.

Or if your tiles aren't actually moving/changing frame-to-frame [blit them into one large texture](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget) and render that instead.

Longer-term, bug [Sam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Lantinga) on the [mailing list](http://lists.libsdl.org/listinfo.cgi/sdl-libsdl.org) for something like `SDL_RenderCopyBatch()`, similar to `SDL_RenderDrawRects()`.

Comment: An idea is something related to Terraria's blocks. I have huge 2D-array, but I render only cut off.